# Rails 4 has_many :through Cascade Delete Based on Checkbox Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a has_many :through association as follows

```
Customer->
has_many :customer_materials, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :materials, :through => :customer_materials

CustomerMaterial -> #This is the lookout table for a price attribute
belongs_to :customer
belongs_to :material

Material ->
has_many :customer_materials, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :customers, :through => :customer_materials
```

Not all customers have custom pricing like this through the lookup table.  I use the lookup table only if the customer's custom_price boolean is checked.  If the custom_price boolean is false, I use the default prices that are tracked by a price attribute in the Material table.

When I edit the customer and uncheck the custom_price checkbox,  I want to go ahead and trigger a cascade delete on the lookup table.  Here is my controller method for update.  How do I modify the method to do a conditional update based off the custom_price attribute?

```
def update
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  if @customer.update_attributes(customer_params)
    flash[:success] = "Record Updated Successfully"
    redirect_to customers_url
  else
    flash.now[:error] = @customer.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :delete_custom_prices, :unless => Proc.new {|model| model.custom_price? }

  def delete_custom_prices
    customer_materials.delete_all
  end
end
```

Comment: I'm getting an error maybe because in postgres, a boolean value is stored as TRUE instead of 1 and FALSE instead of 0. Should I change that attribute to integer? edit: this is the value for the custom_pricing checkbox.

Comment: Turns out this is a different problem when rendering the edit view.  I'm going to have to use some javascript to set the checkbox value.  Your solution works except I changed custom_prices.delete_all to customer_materials.delete_all